# Azure Functions: Have a CorrelationId between Http Trigger and Blob Trigger to follow a request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to have a CorrelationId to be able to follow a request from Http Trigger to Blob Trigger in Application insights.

I am creating a CorrelationId in Http Trigger function and want to track same in the blob trigger.

Here is my Http Trigger function:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(ReceiveEvent))]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Inject] ILoggingService loggingService,
            [Inject] IProvideCorrelationIds correlationIds,
            [Inject] IEventMapper eventMapper,
            [Inject] IEventValidator eventValidator,
            [Inject] IEventHandler<ResultDto, Messages.Events.Event> eventHandler)
        {
            var logger = new Logger(loggingService);

            try
            {
                IActionResult actionResult = null;

                correlationIds.CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

                logger.Info($"Event request received");

                var @event = eventMapper.Map(requestBody);

                if (eventValidator.Validate(req, @event, logger, ref actionResult))
                {
                    var response = await eventHandler.HandleAsync(@event, logger);
                    actionResult = new OkObjectResult(response);
                }
                return actionResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"Exception while processing {nameof(ReceiveEvent)}", ex,
                  nameof(ReceiveEvent));

                throw;
            }
        }
```

CorrelationId Provider:

```
public class CorrelationIdProvider: IProvideCorrelationIds
    {
        private static readonly AsyncLocal<string> AsyncLocalCorrelationId = new AsyncLocal<string>();

        public string CorrelationId
        {
            get => AsyncLocalCorrelationId.Value;
            set => AsyncLocalCorrelationId.Value = value;
        }
    }
```

Blob Trigger Function:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(ProcessEvent))]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger(BlobStorageContainer.Name + "/{name}",
            Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
            Stream eventBlob, string name,
            [Inject] ILoggingService loggingService,
            [Inject] IEventProcessorService eventProcessor,
            [Inject] IBlobClient blobClient)
        {
            var logger = new Logger(loggingService);
            try
            {
                logger.Info($"Starting blob job tracker for file name {name}",
                    nameof(ProcessEvent));

                //correlationIds.CorrelationId = correlationId;

                var eventContent = eventBlob.ReadAsString();

                var result = await eventProcessor.HandleProcessor(eventContent, logger);

                if (result)
                {
                    await blobClient.DeleteBlobAsync(BlobStorageContainer.Name, name);
                    logger.Info($"Blob deleted successfully file name: {name}");
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Warning($"Unable to process blob job for file with name: {name}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"Unable to process blob job for file with name: {name}", ex,
                    nameof(ProcessEvent));
            }
        }
```

What are the changes I need to do to get CorrelationId in Blob Trigger?

Comment: They should already be a part of the same operation and have the same operation ID. App insights does a lot of the plumbing for you and azure functions does some more. There shouldn't be a need to manually do this

Comment: But how can I capture the same ID in blob trigger?

Comment: That's the point. You don't need to. The correlation information is automatically passed via http headers or whatever other communication protocol is being used (AI does this via telemetry modules/initializer) . I guarantee if you open appinsight and find a telemetry item in the logs from one service and you click the 'show all telemetry' button you will see telemetry from both functions automatically correlated together as a single 'operation'

Comment: I just went through a similar exercise at my new job. I was able to remove all the home grown attempts at correlation (in most cases without adding any additional code). I just had to show everyone how to use the AI dashboard properly. It's all done mostly automatically, and entirely so when using azure services

Comment: You means I don't need to do this "correlationIds.CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();" in http trigger function

Comment: Or Can you please share some tutorial URLs or sample where i can learn how AI is storing correlation automatically?

Comment: Correct. AI will create (amongst several other guid-based IDs) an Operation ID which will be the same for all telemetry within a single correlated context. The other IDs (parent, span, parent span, trace) are all part of the OpenTelemetry effort and are used to aide in the correlation automatically (sometimes aided by the Activity class). What you are creating manually corellates (pun intended) with AppInsights's OperationId which is done automatically for you and will be the same inside of each function/application as your logic flows through the system all starting with a RequestTelemetry

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the two trigger in the same class, use below code you can get id from http trigger:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp86
{
    public class CorrelationIdProvider
    {
        public string id;
        public string CorrelationId
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
    }

    public static class Function1
    {
        public static string id;
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run1(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            CorrelationIdProvider cp = new CorrelationIdProvider();
            cp.CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            log.LogInformation(cp.CorrelationId);
            id = cp.CorrelationId;

            return new OkObjectResult(cp.CorrelationId);
        }
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run2(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            CorrelationIdProvider cp = new CorrelationIdProvider();
            cp.CorrelationId = id;
            log.LogInformation(cp.CorrelationId);

            return new OkObjectResult(cp.CorrelationId);
        }
    }
}
```

My second trigger is http trigger, you can change it to blob trigger.:)